# How to set Paper.js Canvas background fill color (No CSS background)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I'm working on a paper.js animation. The animation contains multiple paths. I'm using [ccapture.js](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js) to export the animation in a video.
What ccapture.js does is capture the drawing on canvas frame by frame and convert it into video.

The problem I'm facing is, in the animation I want the background color of canvas to be white. If I set the background color of canvas using css `background-color: white;` ccapture will ignore this color and the background color in the captured video will be black as white color is not drawn on canvas and is only background of the element. I've tested this method with no luck.

I've tried adding a white rectangle path in animation but it hides the animation and all I could see is the white rectangle. I found the reference of a function to put the white rectangle at back using `sentToBack()` from following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25791052/1433217), I'm using it like this:

```
var rect = new Path.Rectangle({
    point: [0, 0],
    size: [view.size.width / 2, view.size.height / 2],
    strokeColor: 'white',
    fillColor: 'white',
    selected: true
});
rect.sendToBack();
```

I can't find the reference of this function in paper.js documentation so I'm not sure if I'm using it the right way.

I've also tried creating the rectangle at starting of paperscript as well as ending of paperscript, thought the order of creating paths might solve the issue. But its not helping either.

Is there any other way using which I can set the background fill color of canvas to white. Please ask me for more details.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @Kostas answer. I checked again the code of other paths I created. I used `blendMode: 'screen'` with other paths that I created. That was causing other paths to blend with screen: [docs](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#blendmode)
After removing this property it worked as expected.

**Related Info**: `sendToBack()` works as I've used in the code.

The paths are stacked in the order they are created in paperscript. First created path will be under all other paths (unless z-index is not changed using `sendToBack()` or `insertBelow()` method)

Hope it will help others..

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the color after the `rect` creation.

Try this:

```js
var rect = new Path.Rectangle({
    point: [0, 0],
    size: [view.size.width / 2, view.size.height / 2],
    strokeColor: 'white',
    selected: true
});
rect.sendToBack();
rect.fillColor = '#ff0000';
```

Comment: Thanks @Kostas! Its working this way. Can you explain how it works?

Comment: ok my bad.. it was actually the `blendmode: 'screen'` which was causing the issue. it works even if we mention `fillColor` in constructor object.